# Como agregar caracteres al comienzo y al final de una linea con notepad y expresiones regulares

Tags: regex, notepad++

Necesito que cada linea que cada linea este el principio y al final en comillas simple y que este separado por comas(,), se que por medio del editor de notepad++ a través de expresiones regulares se puede realizar, pero desconozco como.

Ejemplo:

```
2CO332
021CS615877
2CO247
2CO246
2CO60

'2CO332',
'021CS615877',
'2CO247',
'2CO246',
'2CO60'
```

Comment: Podrias buscar el saldo de línea y reemplazarlo por ', ENTER '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con este patrón podrías hacer el reemplazo que quieres, lo único es que te quedaría por ajustar a mano la primera y última:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los valores del reemplazo:

Buscar por: `\r\n`
Reemplazar con: `',\r\n'`

Es importante que digas que el "modo de búsqueda" es `Extendido`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Camilo Bernal, me has ahorrado un monton de trabajo. En mi caso tenía que poner comilla de abertura y cierre (" ") a 88512 líneas de texto. Realmente ví tutoriales en Youtube y ninguno acerto con lo que quería. Gracias!